# Using JQuery UI Dialog to edit ASP GridView data

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui, gridview, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm trying to use a jQueryUI Dialog to edit some data from any row in a gridview that the user clicks on. So far, my gridview looks like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
         OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" 
         style="margin: 2px 5px 5px 15px;" >
         <Columns>
              <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit">
                   <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton Id="btnEditRow" Text="Edit" OnClientClick="EditRecordOpen('editForm');return false;" OnClick="btnEditRow_Click" runat="server" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
              </asp:TemplateField>
              <asp:BoundField DataField="StartTime" HeaderText="Start Time" 
                    SortExpression="StartTime" >
               </asp:BoundField>
               <asp:BoundField DataField="Furnace" HeaderText="Furnace" 
                     SortExpression="Furnace">
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="OperatorComments" HeaderText="Operator Comments" 
                      SortExpression="OperatorComments" ControlStyle-Width="200px">
                </asp:BoundField>
          </Columns>
 </asp:GridView>
```

It just has 4 coulmns, an edit button, start time, furnace and comments. When the user click the edit button, a jQueryUI Dialog pops up. I have that part set up. But the part I'm having trouble with is passing the data from the row to the dialog. This is the markup for my dialog. (Only the comments field will be edited).

```
<div id="editForm">
     <asp:UpdatePanel ID="editRecordPanel" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="true" runat="server">
          <ContentTemplate>
                Furnace: <asp:Label ID="lblFurnace" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label><br />
                Start Time: <asp:Label ID="lblStartTime" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label><br />
                Comments: <asp:TextBox ID="txtEditComments" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
                <asp:Button ID="btnSaveRecord" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="btnSaveRecord_Click" />
           </ContentTemplate>
     </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

This is my javascript for handling the popup:

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#editForm").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            draggable: true,
            title: "Edit Record",
            width: 500,
            resizable: false,
            open: function (type, data) {
                $(this).parent().appendTo("form");
            }
        });
    });

    function EditRecordOpen(id) {
        $("#" + id).dialog("open");
        // found something like this from a page I found on google
        $("#lblFurnace").html($("#Furnace", $(this).closest("tr")).html());
    }

    function EditRecordClose(id) {
        $("#" + id).dialog("close");
    }
```

This is the code for that I'm using behind the dialog opening:

```
private void CloseDialog(string dialogId)
{
    string script = string.Format(@"EditRecordClose('{0}');", dialogId);
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, typeof(Page), UniqueID, script, true);
}

protected void btnSaveRecord_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CloseDialog("editForm");
}

protected void btnEditRow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var editLink = ((LinkButton)sender);
    editRecordPanel.Update();
}
```

I'm trying to figure out how to get the data from the row to the dialog. I've searched Google a bit but what I've read involved solutions that required me changing the code that I had in place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use another implementation to get this working. What I did was to use TemplateFields inside my GridView, and chose to edit rows inline.

In my question here ([Cascading Dropdowns in asp gridview, not getting .asmx methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20530171/cascading-dropdowns-in-asp-gridview-not-getting-asmx-methods)), you can see how my gridView was changed to allow editing.