# Cascading Dropdowns in asp gridview, not getting .asmx methods

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, asmx

I've been following the instructions on this page:
http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.com/2009/02/ajax-cascading-dropdownlist-database.html
to set up 2 cascading dropdown lists in my gridview but there is no data coming in from the .asmx page.

This is my .asmx page:

```
public class SorSubsystemsCascade : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    public SorSubsystemsCascade ()
    {
        //InitializeComponents();
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public CascadingDropDownNameValue[] GetSubsystems(string knowCategoryValue, string category)
    {
        // get a list of subsystems
        string url = @"http://osw-hml3mes.novelis.biz:3020/Preheat/Downtime/Subsystems";
        List<SorSubsystem> subsystems = new List<SorSubsystem>();
        subsystems = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<SorSubsystem>>(new WebClient().DownloadString(url));

        // create a list of drop downs
        List<CascadingDropDownNameValue> subsystemsList = new List<CascadingDropDownNameValue>();

        foreach(SorSubsystem sub in subsystems)
        {
            subsystemsList.Add(new CascadingDropDownNameValue(sub.Description, sub.SubSystemCode));
        }

        return subsystemsList.ToArray();
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public CascadingDropDownNameValue[] GetReasons(string knownCategoryValues, string category)
    {
        List<CascadingDropDownNameValue> reasons = new List<CascadingDropDownNameValue>();
        string url = @"http://osw-hml3mes.novelis.biz:3020/Preheat/Downtime/Reasons";

        List<SorReason> loadReason = new List<SorReason>();
        loadReason = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<SorReason>>(new WebClient().DownloadString(url));

        foreach (SorReason res in loadReason)
        {
            if(res.SubSystemCode == "A")
                reasons.Add(new CascadingDropDownNameValue(res.Description, res.SubSystemCode));
        }

        return reasons.ToArray();
    }
}
```

For the data, I am getting a JSON data from a page and deserializing it into a list of objects.

These are my objects:
SorReason:

```
public class SorReason {
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string ShortDescription { get; set; }    
        public string Description { get; set; }    
        public string SubSystemCode { get; set; }   
        public string DisplayReason { get { return Code + " - " + ShortDescription; } }                
 }
```

SorSubsystem:

```
public class SorSubsystem {
        public string SubSystemCode { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

The reason dropdownlist is using the subsystem dropdown list as it's parent. For some reason, the subsystem dropdown list isn't populating correctly. It looks like the .asmx service isn't being called.

I did place this in my ScriptManager tag

```
<Services>
     <asp:ServiceReference Path="SorSubsystemCascade.asmx" />
</Services>
```

This is the entire markup for my page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="SorGrid.aspx.cs" Inherits="SorDowntimeWebApp.SorGrid" EnableEventValidation="false" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="asp" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Preheat SOR</title>
        <link rel="Stylesheet" href="Common/JqueryUI/css/custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.css" />
        <style type="text/css">
            body { font-family: Museo, Arial; }
            h1 { background: #8F1626; color: #BFC5C5; width: 50%; }
            #dataGridWrapper { height: 400px; width: 100%; }
            #lblError { color: Red; font-size: 12pt; }
        </style>
        <%--<script type="text/javascript" src="Common/jQueryUI/js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>--%>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="Common/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="Common/jQueryUI/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                // maxDate: 0 sets the max date allowable to today (users can't pick tomorrow as an option)
                $("#txtStartDate").datepicker({
                    showOn: "button",
                    buttonImage: "Common/Images/calendar.gif",
                    buttonImageOnly: true,
                    buttonText: "",
                    maxDate: 0
                });
                $("#txtEndDate").datepicker({
                    showOn: "button",
                    buttonImage: "Common/Images/calendar.gif",
                    buttonImageOnly: true,
                    buttonText: "",
                    maxDate: 0
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <asp:ScriptManager ID="mainScriptManager" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
            <ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="toolkitScriptManager" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true" />
            <div id="formWrapper">
                <div id="toolbarWrapper">
                    <div id="dateSearchBar">
                        <h1>Preheat SOR<asp:Label ID="lblError" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label></h1>
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="lblStart" runat="server">Start Date:&nbsp;&nbsp;</asp:Label><asp:TextBox ID="txtStartDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="lblEnd" runat="server">End Date:&nbsp;&nbsp;</asp:Label><asp:TextBox ID="txtEndDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" onclick="btnSearch_Click" />
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:Button ID="btnRefresh" runat="server" Text="Refresh" onclick="btnRefresh_Click" />
                    </div>
                    <div id="toolbar">
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:Button ID="btnExport" runat="server" Text="Export to Excel" onclick="btnExport_Click" />
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="button" value="Pareto" onclick="window.open('SorPareto.aspx', 'Pareto')" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="dataGridWrapper">
                    <asp:GridView AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="Black" 
                            ID="GridView1" OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing" 
                            OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating" runat="server" style="margin: 2px 5px 5px 15px;">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnEdit" runat="server" Text="Edit" commandName="Edit" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:linkbutton id="btnUpdate" runat="server" commandname="Update" text="Update" />
                                    <asp:linkbutton id="btnCancel" runat="server" commandname="Cancel" text="Cancel" />
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="StartTime" HeaderText="Start Time" SortExpression="StartTime" ReadOnly="true">
                                <ItemStyle Width="170px" />
                            </asp:BoundField>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="EndTime" HeaderText="End Time" SortExpression="EndTime" ReadOnly="true">
                                <ItemStyle Width="170px" />
                            </asp:BoundField>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Duration" HeaderText="Duration" SortExpression="Duration" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="False" ReadOnly="true">
                                <ItemStyle Width="60px" />
                            </asp:BoundField>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Furnace" HeaderText="Furnace" SortExpression="Furnace" ReadOnly="true">
                                <ItemStyle Width="40px" />
                                </asp:BoundField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Subsystem" SortExpression="Subsystem">
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddEditSubsystem" runat="server" Width="150px" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddEditSubsystem_SelectedIndexChanged">
                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                    <ajaxToolkit:CascadingDropDown ID="cddSubsystem" runat="server" Category="Subsystem" TargetControlID="ddEditSubsystem" 
                                            ServiceMethod="GetSubsystems" PromptText="Subsystem">
                                    </ajaxToolkit:CascadingDropDown>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblSubsystem" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Subsystem") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <ItemStyle Width="210px" />
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Reason" SortExpression="Reason">
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddEditReason" runat="server" Width="100px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddEditReason_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                    <ajaxToolkit:CascadingDropDown ID="cddReason" runat="server" Category="Reasons" TargetControlID="ddEditReason" ParentControlID="ddEditSubsystem" 
                                            ServiceMethod="GetReasons" PromptText="Reason">
                                    </ajaxToolkit:CascadingDropDown>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblReason" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Reason") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <ItemStyle Width="300px" />
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="F/S" SortExpression="ForceScheduleFlag">
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddEditForcedSched" runat="server" Width="40px">
                                        <asp:ListItem>F</asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem>S</asp:ListItem>
                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblForcedSched" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ForceScheduleFlag") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <ItemStyle Width="25px" />
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Operator Comments" SortExpression="OperatorComments">
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEditOperatorComments" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("OperatorComments") %>' Width="300px"></asp:TextBox>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblOperatorComments" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("OperatorComments") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <ItemStyle Width="300px" />
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                        </Columns>
                        <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCC99" ForeColor="Black" />
                        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#DF7E26" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#000000" Height="30px" HorizontalAlign="Center"/>
                        <PagerStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#CC3333" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F7F7F7" />
                        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4B4B4B" />
                        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E5E5E5" />
                        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#242121" />
                        <RowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    </asp:GridView>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you see the request going out to the web service via the browser tools (F12 Tools for IE, Firebug for Firefox or Chrome Developer Tools)? If so, what is the HTTP status code returned? 200? 400? 500?

Comment: I don't see a request but I'm getting the error `GET http://localhost:52284/SorSubsystemCascade.asmx/jsdebug 500 (Internal Server Error)` and this error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'UI' of undefined`

Comment: Does the `GetSubsystems()` web method work?

Comment: I'm not sure, it looks like my .asmx file isn't even loading. It's as if the dropdowns aren't able to access it.

Comment: Do you have to use an .asmx web service?

Comment: I guess not, I'm just trying to get cascading dropdown lists to work inside my gridview. How would you approach it? Is there an easier way?

Comment: See my answer for using ASP.NET AJAX Page Methods instead of an .asmx web service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the page of your grid, you can make `static` methods called ASP.NET AJAX Page Methods. They are essentially page-hosted web service methods, like this:

```
[WebMethod]
public static CascadingDropDownNameValue[] GetSubsystems(string knowCategoryValue, string category)
{
    // get a list of subsystems
    string url = @"http://osw-hml3mes.novelis.biz:3020/Preheat/Downtime/Subsystems";
    List<SorSubsystem> subsystems = new List<SorSubsystem>();
    subsystems = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<SorSubsystem>>(new WebClient().DownloadString(url));

    // create a list of drop downs
    List<CascadingDropDownNameValue> subsystemsList = new List<CascadingDropDownNameValue>();

    foreach(SorSubsystem sub in subsystems)
    {
        subsystemsList.Add(new CascadingDropDownNameValue(sub.Description, sub.SubSystemCode));
    }

    return subsystemsList.ToArray();
}

[WebMethod]
public static CascadingDropDownNameValue[] GetReasons(string knownCategoryValues, string category)
{
    List<CascadingDropDownNameValue> reasons = new List<CascadingDropDownNameValue>();
    string url = @"http://osw-hml3mes.novelis.biz:3020/Preheat/Downtime/Reasons";

    List<SorReason> loadReason = new List<SorReason>();
    loadReason = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<SorReason>>(new WebClient().DownloadString(url));

    foreach (SorReason res in loadReason)
    {
        if(res.SubSystemCode == "A")
            reasons.Add(new CascadingDropDownNameValue(res.Description, res.SubSystemCode));
    }

    return reasons.ToArray();
}
```

---

> Note: The logic is identical to the .asmx web service version, but with the addition of the `static` modifier to the methods themselves.

---

Now in your markup, you just need to reference the method name and can omit the `ServicePath` attribute, because the web methods are now local to the page with the grid, like this:

```
<ajaxToolkit:CascadingDropDown ID="cddSubsystem" runat="server" 
    Category="Subsystem" TargetControlID="ddEditSubsystem"     
    ServiceMethod="GetSubsystems" PromptText="Subsystem">
</ajaxToolkit:CascadingDropDown>
```

Comment: That fixed part of it but I'm getting the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'UI' of undefined `. Maybe it has something to do with my version of jQuery? I'm going to try a different version.

Comment: Ok, if after switching versions of jQuery that does not work, then post all of your markup in your question.

Comment: It didn't change anything. I googled the error and it looks like it has something to do with the ajaxControlToolkit assembly. Someone suggested adding the line `<ajaxToolkit: ToolkitScriptManager EnablePartialRendering = "true" runat = "Server" ID = "ScriptManager1" />` Just a sec, I'll post my entire markup

Comment: I was able to get the `Uncaught TypeError` error working. I had 2 script managers but you can only use one. Now, the dropdowns populate!

Comment: @user - ah yes, you can only have one `ScriptManager` for the application, I generally put it in the master page as to avoid duplicates in the content pages.